# clang error invalid version number in -miphoneos-version-min=.sd

Tags: ios, gcc, clang, cross-compiling, rtmp

When i compile `librtmp` for ios, the script shows below:

```
#!/bin/sh

# OS X Yosemite, Xcode 6.1

set -ex

DEVELOPER="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer"
DEVICE_SDK="$DEVELOPER/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS.sdk"
SIMULATOR_SDK="$DEVELOPER/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk"
CURRPATH=`pwd`
SOURCE="rtmpdump"
DSTDIR="librtmp"
LIBSSL=`cd ../OpenSSL/libssl;pwd`
ARCHS="i386 x86_64 armv7 armv7s arm64"

rm -rf $DSTDIR
mkdir $DSTDIR

if [ ! -d $SOURCE ]; then
    git clone git://git.ffmpeg.org/rtmpdump $SOURCE
else
    cd $SOURCE
    git fetch
    cd ..
fi

cd $SOURCE/librtmp

for ARCH in $ARCHS; do
    mkdir -p ../$DSTDIR/$ARCH

    if [[ $ARCH == arm* ]]; then
        SDK=$DEVICE_SDK
    else
        SDK=$SIMULATOR_SDK
    fi

    perl -i -pe 's|^AR=\$\(CROSS_COMPILE\)ar|AR=xcrun ar|' Makefile

    CROSS_COMPILE="$DEVELOPER/usr/bin/" \
    XCFLAGS="-O0 -isysroot $SDK -I$LIBSSL/include -arch $ARCH " \
    XLDFLAGS="-isysroot $SDK -L$LIBSSL/lib -arch $ARCH -miphoneos-version-min=7.0 " \
    make SYS=darwin
    make SYS=darwin prefix="$CURRPATH/$DSTDIR/$ARCH" install
    make clean
done


mkdir -p $CURRPATH/$DSTDIR/lib
cd $CURRPATH/$DSTDIR/$ARCH/lib
LIBS=`ls *.a`
cd $CURRPATH
for LIB in $LIBS; do
    lipo -create `find $DSTDIR -name $LIB` -output $DSTDIR/lib/$LIB
done

cp -rf $DSTDIR/$ARCH/include $DSTDIR

for ARCH in $ARCHS; do
    rm -rf $DSTDIR/$ARCH
done
```

when statement `make SYS=darwin` runs, error shows:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/gcc -Wall -O0 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS.sdk -I/Users/Smeegol/Desktop/AVCodecs2/OpenSSL/libssl/include -arch armv7   -DRTMPDUMP_VERSION=\"v2.4\" -DUSE_OPENSSL  -O2 -fPIC   -c -o rtmp.o rtmp.c
clang: error: invalid version number in '-miphoneos-version-min=.sd'
make: *** [rtmp.o] Error 1
```

Why? I have set `XLDFLAGS="-isysroot $SDK -L$LIBSSL/lib -arch $ARCH -miphoneos-version-min=7.0 "` and why `invalid version number in '-miphoneos-version-min=.sd'` occurs?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and resolved it by changing the `-isysroot` argument from:

> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS.sdk

to:

> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS8.3.sdk

Note that the latter is a symlink to the former on my system.

It appears that clang is implicitly setting `-miphoneos-version-min=` from the iPhoneOSXXX.sdk directory name. Using the link with the version number in it seems to fix the compilation issue.

Comment: Even if such nice default value (based on SDK path) exists, **that does not explain the error reason and/or solution.**

Comment: Is just a Workaround.

Answer (score 0):

The error is little confusing, and may have multiple causes:

- Not all SDKs support all possible `-miphoneos-version-min=` values.
- Or like OP, `-miphoneos-version-min=` is not even being passed to the compiler.