# trying to archive an ios application but getting clang error

Tags: ios, xcode, ionic-framework

I am trying to archive a project for a ios project using xcode.
At the end of the process i have the following error :

> clang: error: invalid version number in '-miphoneos-version-min=8.0   '

I have tried creating a symlink as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28823485/clang-error-invalid-version-number-in-miphoneos-version-min-sd) but with no success. I am out of options.

Any clues ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the reply in the error speaks for itself.
miphoneos-version-min=8.0

Apparantly your project is for a version below 8.0.

Comment: 8.0 is the version of the OSX compiler ?

Comment: Nope, it is the minimum version of iOS that your will app supports. From the wide range of iOS version you can pick your range of iOS version that your app will support.

Comment: I see. I changed the target with Ios and I could archive it.